# Scrape HTML table and create XML in PHP

Tags: php, html, xml, curl

I already wrote a php script that logs into our school note system. But I'm trying to parse the HTML page to xml. But I'm running into some troubles. First of all the html code of the tabel is kinda a mess and I have no clue what to do now.

This is the CURL PHP page: http://koetse.eu/test/curl.php.
This is the source code of the reply: http://pastebin.com/RDawmsnY

I'm trying to change that Messy HTML tabel into a xml file, looking somewhat like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> > 
<notes>
    <name>Jurre (4HC)</name>
            <class>kwt</class>
            <class>netl</class>
                    <note>6.6</note>
                    <note>6.3</note>
                    <note>4.9</note>
                    <se>5.8</se>
            <class>entl</class>
                    <note>7.5</note>
                    <note>7.3</note>
                    <note>7.7</note>
                    <note>10.0</note>
                    <note>6.6</note>
                    <note>9.6</note>
                    <note>6.7</note>
                    <note>6.7</note>
                    <se>8.6</se>
            <class>lv</class>
                    <note>7.8</note>
                    <note>4.8</note>
                    <se>6.3</se>
</notes>
```

ect... (I only did the first 3 rows as an example)

Sorry for using pastebin, But I got into a fight with the max length of a post.

Regards Jurre

Comment: Does it load at all if you do `$d = new DOMDocument(); $d->loadHtml($garbargeHTML);` ?

Comment: Nope Im getting a error, 
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: Tag wissearch:exclude invalid in Entity, line: 3
Catchable fatal error: Object of class DOMDocument could not be converted to string in/public_html/test/xml.php on line 33

Comment: Your error is *not* from parsing, but from attempting to treat DOMDocument as a string (look at line 33). Most likely your DOMDocument loaded fine.

Comment: However much of this data appears to be inserted by javascript, so parsing won't get at it. You may need to do this inside a browser, or at least serialize the DOM tree the browser generates and then work on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty surprised how no-one mentioned TIDY. http://www.w3.org/People/Raggett/tidy/ . Has officially saved my butt a few times. I have managed to load your HTML in a DOM document without an issue after passing the garbage through it.

There is, however, one significant mod I had to do after passing it through tidy - your school's systems output some tags which, whilst they would work perfectly in a XML doc, will just not work in HTML - wisssearch. Search&replace using regular expressions and you've got a valid DOMDocument at the end!

Things to do next:

- Get rid of all those &xAA; marks - regular expressions
- Parse stuff!

(tidy -f errors.txt -m your_file.txt )

Comment: I got it finally parsed to xml using TIDY, however is there a way to clear up this code? http://92.108.180.252/xml.php

Comment: From here, it's manual all the way - find what you want in there, and extract it using a combination of DOMDocument/DOMElement navigation, regular expressions or recursive descent. There's no easy way :-(

Answer (score 0):

That HTML document really does look nasty. I don't think you will be able to parse it with a DOM parser or anything XML like.

I would suggest trying the regular expressions approach.

The class names are presented in a nice unnumbered list, so you can scrape them by finding the `<ul>` and `</ul>` tags then using a regexp to extract the names from the span tags.

Similarly you can find the second occurrence of `<table` and the first occurrence of `</table>`, then regexp within that to get the rows and then cells, and finally discard the span stuff and be left with the numbers.